# Parse text from html tags in xml table

Tags: r, xml

Asked to review questions for grammar and spelling:

```
library(XML)
tbls_all <- readHTMLTable(url_v9)
length(tbls_all)
[1] 34
names(tbls_all)
 [1] "NULL"                "DisplayedQuestions"  "AllQuestions1"      
 [4] "HiddenAnswerTable1"  "HiddenAnswerTable1"  "AllQuestions2"      
 [7] "HiddenAnswerTable2"  "HiddenAnswerTable2"  "AllQuestions3"      
[10] "HiddenAnswerTable3"  "HiddenAnswerTable3"  "AllQuestions4"      
[13] "HiddenAnswerTable4"  "HiddenAnswerTable4"  "AllQuestions5"      
[16] "HiddenAnswerTable5"  "HiddenAnswerTable5"  "AllQuestions6"      
[19] "HiddenAnswerTable6"  "HiddenAnswerTable6"  "AllQuestions7"      
[22] "HiddenAnswerTable7"  "HiddenAnswerTable7"  "AllQuestions8"      
[25] "HiddenAnswerTable8"  "HiddenAnswerTable8"  "AllQuestions9"      
[28] "HiddenAnswerTable9"  "HiddenAnswerTable9"  "AllQuestions10"     
[31] "HiddenAnswerTable10" "HiddenAnswerTable10" "TotalsTable"        
[34] "HiddenTable"
```

just interested in `AllQuestions`, so

```
tbls_q <- tbls_all[grep('AllQuestions\\d', names(tbls_all))]
length(tbls_q)
[1] 10
names(tbls_q[[1]])
[1] "V1" "V2" "V3" "V4"
```

The questions are in `V1`

```
tbls_q[[1]]$V1[2]
[1] "<strong>Now I am going to evaluate how well you can remember the names of some common items. First, I will show you pictures of 16 items that I want you to remember. Each item belongs to a different category. For example, 'type of reading materials' is a category. I will show you the items four at a time and ask you to tell me which item belongs with each category and then to immediately recall the items when I tell you their categories. Later, I will ask you to recall all of the items I have shown you. For any items you miss, I will tell you the categories to help you recall more items. You will have 3 tries to recall the items.</strong>(726368 - WAS_Card1_Intro)"
> tbls_q[[1]]$V1[4]
[1] "<br><br><font color=\"blue\"><i>Bear - Correctly Named?</i></font>(726370 - WAS_Card1_Word1_Name)"
> tbls_q[[1]]$V1[3]
[1] "<font color=\"blue\"><i>Place Worksheet 1 in front of the subject.</i></font><br><br><strong>There are 4 pictures on this worksheet. When I tell you a category, point to the item that is in that category and tell me its name. <br><br><br>Point to the 4–Legged Animal and tell me its name.</strong><br><br><font color=\"blue\"><i>Bear - Correctly Identified?</i></font>(726369 - WAS_Card1_Word1_Identify)"
```

At which point, I'm stuck for how to further extract the text without embedded html <tags, report what it says, report what it should say and which variable, `(726369` for example, the question is. I can imagine some regex approaches, but, fragile...